# Sqldf Query in R Returning 0 Rows

Tags: r, sqldf

I have an internal dataset of employee information and I am trying to run a basic `sqldf` function to get the count of employees with the type `Regular`. I am using and have brought into R Studio the following fields: `EEID` (numeric), `Employee_Type` (character).

I am able to get a basic count of all rows:

```rb
start_hc <- sqldf("SELECT COUNT('Employee.ID') FROM global_hc")
print(start_hc)
COUNT('Employee.ID')
> 938
```

But when I add something into the WHERE clause I get 0 results:

```rb
start_hc <- sqldf("SELECT COUNT('Employee.ID') FROM global_hc WHERE 'Employee.Type' IN ('Regular')")
print(start_hc)
> 0
```

I have tried referring to the column `Employee_Type` as `Employee.Type` and 
`Employee Type`. I just cannot figure out what is going on and why the query is returning `0`. Please let me know if you need more information and I will provide it.

Comment: The "Regular" type in your database might contain spaces or non printable characters?

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page when posting questions. This asks for reproducible code which means examples should include input, expected output and all library statements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to surround the variable with a quote.

```
start_hc <- sqldf("SELECT COUNT(Employee.ID) 
                  FROM global_hc 
                  WHERE Employee.Type IN ('Regular')")
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, though when I try removing the quotes I get this error: Error: no such column: Employee.Type

Comment: Check the exact spelling for the name of your "Employee type" variable. In your introduction, you said `Employee_Type` but in your code you typed: `Employee.Type`. So which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are used to enclose constant strings, not column names.  Use double quotes or square brackets to enclose column names.   If the column name is a syntactically valid name for SQL then you don't need to either; however, in this case you do because dot is an SQL operator.

For example, using the builtin `iris` data frame this gives 0 because the string `Petal.Length` does not equal 1.4

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select count(*) from iris where 'Petal.Length' = 1.4")
##   count(*)
## 1        0
```

The correct way to do this is to use double quotes or square brackets:

```
sqldf("select count(*) from iris where [Petal.Length] = 1.4")
##   count(*)
## 1       13
```